# How to select audio channels and subtitles in a video stream, using vlc lib for Android?

Tags: android, audio, vlc, subtitle

I am working in a stream video player in Android and need to show the subtitles of this stream (when they exist) and also show a way for the user to select one of the audio channels presents in the stream.
I am switching from Android MediaPlayer to VlcLib to be able to do it.
But I can't find any examples about how to do it.

Has anybody already done this? Can you share some example or show a clue?

Thanks very much for any help.

My code, wich is based on an example found in internet, is:

```
package com.wass08.vlcsimpleplayer;

import com.wass08.vlcsimpleplayer.util.SystemUiHider;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.videolan.libvlc.EventHandler;
import org.videolan.libvlc.IVideoPlayer;
import org.videolan.libvlc.LibVLC;
import org.videolan.libvlc.Media;
import org.videolan.libvlc.MediaList;

import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * An example full-screen activity that shows and hides the system UI (i.e.
 * status bar and navigation/system bar) with user interaction.
 *
 * @see SystemUiHider
 */
public class FullscreenVlcPlayer extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, IVideoPlayer
{
    private String urlToStream;

    // Display Surface
    private LinearLayout vlcContainer;
    private SurfaceView mSurface;
    private SurfaceView mSubtitlesSurface;
    private SurfaceHolder holder;
    private SurfaceHolder mSubtitlesSurfaceHolder;

    // Overlay / Controls
    private FrameLayout vlcOverlay;
    private ImageView vlcButtonPlayPause;
    private Handler handlerOverlay;
    private Runnable runnableOverlay;
    private Handler handlerSeekbar;
    private Runnable runnableSeekbar;
    private SeekBar vlcSeekbar;
    private TextView vlcDuration;
    private TextView overlayTitle;

    // media player
    private LibVLC libvlc;
    private int mVideoWidth;
    private int mVideoHeight;
    private final static int VideoSizeChanged = -1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Retrieve our url
        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        urlToStream = b.getString("url", null);

        // HIDE THE ACTION BAR
        getActionBar().hide();

        // SETUP THE UI
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen_vlc_player);

        // VLC
        vlcContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.vlc_container);
        mSurface = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.vlc_surface);

        mSubtitlesSurface = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.subtitles_surface);

        // OVERLAY / CONTROLS
        vlcOverlay = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.vlc_overlay);
        vlcButtonPlayPause = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.vlc_button_play_pause);
        vlcSeekbar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.vlc_seekbar);
        vlcDuration = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.vlc_duration);

        overlayTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.vlc_overlay_title);
        overlayTitle.setText(urlToStream);

        // AUTOSTART
        playMovie();
    }

    private void setSubtitles()
    {
        /* Only show the subtitles surface when using "Full Acceleration" mode */
        //if (libvlc.getHardwareAcceleration() == 2)
        //{
            mSubtitlesSurface.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        //}

        Map<Integer, String> mSubtitleTracksList;
        Map<Integer, String> mAudioTracksList;

        int numSubtitleTracks = libvlc.getSpuTracksCount();
        int numAudioTracks    = libvlc.getAudioTracksCount();

        mSubtitleTracksList = libvlc.getSpuTrackDescription();
        mAudioTracksList = libvlc.getAudioTrackDescription();

        if (mSubtitleTracksList != null && mSubtitleTracksList.size() > 0)
        {

        }

        if (mAudioTracksList != null && mAudioTracksList.size() > 0)
        {

        }

        Log.d("LIBVLC_PLAYER", "Number of Subtitles Tracks = " + numSubtitleTracks);
        Log.d("LIBVLC_PLAYER", "Number of Audio Tracks = " + numAudioTracks);

        int i = 0;

        for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : mSubtitleTracksList.entrySet())
        {
            Log.d("LIBVLC_PLAYER", "Subtitle Track " + i + " = " + entry.getValue().toString());
            i++;
        }

        libvlc.setSpuTrack(0);

        i = 0;

        for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry2 : mAudioTracksList.entrySet())
        {
            Log.d("LIBVLC_PLAYER", "Audio Track " + i + " = " + entry2.getValue().toString());
            i++;
        }

        libvlc.setAudioTrack(0);
    }

    private final SurfaceHolder.Callback mSubtitlesSurfaceCallback = new SurfaceHolder.Callback()
    {
        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height)
        {
            if (libvlc != null)
            {
                libvlc.attachSubtitlesSurface(holder.getSurface());
                Log.d("LIBVLC_PLAYER", "SurfaceHolder.Callback: width: " + width + " height: " + height);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder)
        {
            Log.d("LIBVLC_PLAYER", "SurfaceHolder.Callback -> surfaceCreated");
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder)
        {
            libvlc.detachSubtitlesSurface();
            Log.d("LIBVLC_PLAYER", "SurfaceHolder.Callback -> surfaceDestroyed");
        }
    };

    private void showOverlay()
    {
        vlcOverlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    private void hideOverlay()
    {
        vlcOverlay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    private void setupControls()
    {
        getActionBar().hide();
        // PLAY PAUSE
        vlcButtonPlayPause.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view)
                    {
                        if (libvlc.isPlaying())
                        {
                            libvlc.pause();
                            vlcButtonPlayPause.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_play_over_video));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            libvlc.play();
                            vlcButtonPlayPause.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_pause_over_video));
                        }
                    }
                }
        );

        // SEEKBAR
        handlerSeekbar = new Handler();
        runnableSeekbar = new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                if (libvlc != null)
                {
                    long curTime = libvlc.getTime();
                    long totalTime = (long) (curTime / libvlc.getPosition());
                    int minutes = (int) (curTime / (60 * 1000));
                    int seconds = (int) ((curTime / 1000) % 60);
                    int endMinutes = (int) (totalTime / (60 * 1000));
                    int endSeconds = (int) ((totalTime / 1000) % 60);
                    String duration = String.format("%02d:%02d / %02d:%02d", minutes, seconds, endMinutes, endSeconds);
                    vlcSeekbar.setProgress((int) (libvlc.getPosition() * 100));
                    vlcDuration.setText(duration);
                }
                handlerSeekbar.postDelayed(runnableSeekbar, 1000);
            }
        };

        runnableSeekbar.run();
        vlcSeekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(
                new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b)
                    {
                        Log.v("NEW POS", "pos is : " + i);
                        //if (i != 0)
                        //    libvlc.setPosition(((float) i / 100.0f));
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar)
                    {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar)
                    {

                    }
                }
        );

        // OVERLAY
        handlerOverlay = new Handler();
        runnableOverlay = new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                vlcOverlay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                toggleFullscreen(true);
            }
        };
        final long timeToDisappear = 3000;
        handlerOverlay.postDelayed(runnableOverlay, timeToDisappear);
        vlcContainer.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view)
                    {
                        vlcOverlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        handlerOverlay.removeCallbacks(runnableOverlay);
                        handlerOverlay.postDelayed(runnableOverlay, timeToDisappear);
                    }
                }
        );
    }

    public void playMovie()
    {
        if (libvlc != null && libvlc.isPlaying())
        {
            return;
        }
        vlcContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder = mSurface.getHolder();
        holder.addCallback(this);
        createPlayer(urlToStream);
    }

    private void toggleFullscreen(boolean fullscreen)
    {
        WindowManager.LayoutParams attrs = getWindow().getAttributes();
        if (fullscreen)
        {
            attrs.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
            vlcContainer.setSystemUiVisibility(
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
            );
        }
        else
        {
            attrs.flags &= ~WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
        }
        getWindow().setAttributes(attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
    {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        setSize(mVideoWidth, mVideoHeight);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        //releasePlayer();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        releasePlayer();
    }

    /**
     * **********
     * Surface
     * ***********
     */

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder)
    {
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceholder, int format,
                               int width, int height)
    {
        if (libvlc != null)
        {
            libvlc.attachSurface(surfaceholder.getSurface(), this);
        }
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceholder)
    {
    }

    private void setSize(int width, int height)
    {
        mVideoWidth = width;
        mVideoHeight = height;
        if (mVideoWidth * mVideoHeight <= 1)
        {
            return;
        }

        // get screen size
        int w = getWindow().getDecorView().getWidth();
        int h = getWindow().getDecorView().getHeight();

        // getWindow().getDecorView() doesn't always take orientation into
        // account, we have to correct the values
        boolean isPortrait = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
        if (w > h && isPortrait || w < h && !isPortrait)
        {
            int i = w;
            w = h;
            h = i;
        }

        float videoAR  = (float) mVideoWidth / (float) mVideoHeight;
        float screenAR = (float) w / (float) h;

        if (screenAR < videoAR)
        {
            h = (int) (w / videoAR);
        }
        else
        {
            w = (int) (h * videoAR);
        }

        // force surface buffer size
        if (holder != null)
        {
            holder.setFixedSize(mVideoWidth, mVideoHeight);
        }

        // set display size
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = mSurface.getLayoutParams();
        lp.width = w;
        lp.height = h;
        mSurface.setLayoutParams(lp);
        mSurface.invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    public void setSurfaceSize(int width, int height, int visible_width,
                               int visible_height, int sar_num, int sar_den)
    {
        Message msg = Message.obtain(mHandler, VideoSizeChanged, width, height);
        msg.sendToTarget();
    }

    /**
     * **********
     * Player
     * ***********
     */

    private void createPlayer(String media)
    {
        releasePlayer();
        setupControls();
        try
        {
            if (media.length() > 0)
            {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, media, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.setGravity(
                        Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0,
                        0
                );
                toast.show();
            }

            // Create a new media player
            libvlc = LibVLC.getInstance();
            libvlc.setHardwareAcceleration(LibVLC.HW_ACCELERATION_FULL);
            libvlc.eventVideoPlayerActivityCreated(true);
            libvlc.setSubtitlesEncoding("");
            libvlc.setAout(LibVLC.AOUT_OPENSLES);
            libvlc.setTimeStretching(true);
            libvlc.setChroma("RV32");
            libvlc.setVerboseMode(true);
            LibVLC.restart(this);
            EventHandler.getInstance().addHandler(mHandler);
            holder.setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBX_8888);
            holder.setKeepScreenOn(true);

            mSubtitlesSurfaceHolder = mSubtitlesSurface.getHolder();
            mSubtitlesSurfaceHolder.setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
            mSubtitlesSurface.setZOrderMediaOverlay(true);
            //mSubtitlesSurface.setZOrderOnTop(true);
            mSubtitlesSurfaceHolder.setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
            mSubtitlesSurfaceHolder.addCallback(mSubtitlesSurfaceCallback);


            MediaList list = libvlc.getMediaList();
            list.clear();
            list.add(new Media(libvlc, LibVLC.PathToURI(media)), false);


            libvlc.setVolume(100);
            libvlc.playIndex(0);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Could not create Vlc Player", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    private void releasePlayer()
    {
        if (handlerSeekbar != null && runnableSeekbar != null)
        {
            handlerSeekbar.removeCallbacks(runnableSeekbar);
        }
        EventHandler.getInstance().removeHandler(mHandler);
        if (libvlc == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        libvlc.stop();
        libvlc.detachSurface();
        holder = null;
        libvlc.closeAout();

        mVideoWidth = 0;
        mVideoHeight = 0;
    }

    /**
     * **********
     * Events
     * ***********
     */

    private Handler mHandler = new MyHandler(this);

    private static class MyHandler extends Handler
    {
        private WeakReference<FullscreenVlcPlayer> mOwner;

        public MyHandler(FullscreenVlcPlayer owner)
        {
            mOwner = new WeakReference<FullscreenVlcPlayer>(owner);
        }

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg)
        {
            FullscreenVlcPlayer player = mOwner.get();

            // Player events
            if (msg.what == VideoSizeChanged)
            {
                player.setSize(msg.arg1, msg.arg2);
                return;
            }

            // Libvlc events
            Bundle b = msg.getData();
            switch (b.getInt("event"))
            {
                case EventHandler.MediaPlayerEndReached:
                    player.releasePlayer();
                    break;
                case EventHandler.MediaPlayerPlaying:
                    player.setSubtitles();
                    break;
                case EventHandler.MediaPlayerPaused:
                case EventHandler.MediaPlayerStopped:
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not for Android, but I think could help you

```
/* Create a new item */
media = libvlc_media_new_path (inst, "BlackBerry.3gp");

/* Create a media player playing environement */
mediaplayer = libvlc_media_player_new_from_media (media);

/* play the media_player */
libvlc_media_player_play (mediaplayer);

//*****************************************************************************
//*****************************************************************************
//********* Subtitle section. Must be after libvlc_media_player_play **********
//*****************************************************************************
//*****************************************************************************
int temp = libvlc_video_set_subtitle_file(mediaplayer, "NewSubFile.srt");
printf("sub status=%d\n", temp);

temp = libvlc_video_set_subtitle_file(mediaplayer, "BlackBerry.srt");
printf("sub status=%d\n", temp);

int sub_count = libvlc_video_get_spu_count(mediaplayer);
printf("sub count=%d\n", sub_count);

//*****************************************************************************
//*****************************************************************************
//*****************************************************************************
//*****************************************************************************
//*****************************************************************************

sleep (10); /* Let it play a bit */

/* No need to keep the media now */
libvlc_media_release (media);
/* Stop playing */
libvlc_media_player_stop (mediaplayer);

/* Free the media_player */
libvlc_media_player_release (mediaplayer);
```